# How to use session inside webpages?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trouble with **session**; I know it theoretically but I encountered with it how to use **session** , **transferring** username to other page  and adding **logout** in order to clear the current logged account information.
Since I have no idea of session usage I commented it.

This is the checklogin.php

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    include("database.php");

    // username and password sent from form
    $name=$_POST['email'];
    $password=$_POST['pwd'];
    //select data from database

    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE usermail='$name' && userpasswd='$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

    if( $count == 1) {
        // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "search.php"
        //session_register("$name");
        //session_register("$password");
        //$_SESSION['name']= $name;
        header("location:jcte/index.php");
    } else {
        $msg = "Wrong Username or Password. Please retry";
        header("location:ErrorPage.html");      
    }
?>
```

Comment: Read [Session basic usage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

Comment: First things first: Please don't use mysql.* functions, they are depreciated. Use mysqli (mysql improved) instead.

Comment: A good place to begin learning about the features of a language is to read the [language documentation](http://www.php.net/docs.php)

Comment: The page that I want to add **Logout** is the ** header("location:jcte/index.php");**

Comment: do you get any errors @ensberiyu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the line

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

add

```
if ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $data['usermail'];
}
```

Now session created.Call this session in **jcte/index.php** page as:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "welcome $_SESSION['user']";
?>
```

Unset the session in logout.php page as:

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['user']);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks dear, I appreciate your understanding that what I want to do at all.

Answer (score 0):

Always start session page with `session_start().`If you want to use session first assign session a value like this :

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = 'Mahmood';
```

And when you want to access get it like this :

```
echo $_SESSION['username'];
OR
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

And unset this session like this :

```
unset($_SESSION['username']);
```

Some Details are [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp).

Comment: Thanks Mahmood! ok can you let me where to put those codes? I have homepage that is  **header("location:jcte/index.php");** and the above checklogin

Comment: First of all study some tutorials about session.You can use session on any page you like.But always start session on first line of code after that assign or get or unset session.

Comment: Ok  at this semester I am taking it. I understand How to start session and for logout **"unset($_SESSION['username']);" **But only where to use **echo $_SESSION['username'];**

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user']="Varma"; //intializing the session['user'];
    echo $_SESSION['user'];   // displaying the data  
    unset($_SESSION['user']); // destroying the session data.
?>
```

but you have to initialize `session_start();` in all web pages where you have need to access that session variables.