# Sending a specific row to another PHP document

Tags: php

I have a HTML form that displays all the entries in my database.

So each entry has a row and a button for each.

I am trying to send the selection information to another PHP document so I can display the selection there.

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM event");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

?>

<form class='table-form' method='post' action="bookevents.php">

<tr>

    <td>
        <?php echo ($row['event_name']); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo ($row['event_date']); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo ($row['event_time']); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo ($row['event_venue']); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo ($row['event_cost']); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Book now'>
    </td>
</tr>

</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

How would I get it that it sent the data across and how would I display it there?

Comment: Use => [**sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Comment: Would it work to use hidden inputs? `<input type="hidden"...`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Could you give me an example of how I would use it?

Comment: Noticed a quick question earlier, only thing wrong with it was something small, which someone answered in a comment. Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21095943/1415724 and the link I gave you above.

Comment: and this (Q&A) => http://stackoverflow.com/q/20838973/1415724 there are too many links on SO that I have to post them here. They're just going to eat up the thread.

Comment: Sidenote: `<form>` is not allowed as a direct child of `<table>` - invalid HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an ID to your form, then replace:

```
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Book now'>
```

With:

```
<button onclick="var f = document.getElementById('myId'); 
                 f.action='bookevents.php?id=<?=$row['event_id'] ?>';
                 f.submit()">Book now</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you probably only need to pass an id that corresponds to the row over to your booking script.  I'm assuming you have an id in each record.  If not, you need one.  Instead of an `<input>` tag, make a regular link.  You can style it to look more like a button.

```
<a href="/bookNow.php?booking=<?php echo ($row['event_id']); ?>">Book Now</a>
```

Substitute your id column's name for 'event_id'.  In your booking script, look for a GET parameter named "booking" and query for that id to get the record your user has selected.

Comment: Do note - this exposes the id in the URL.  If you are concerned about hiding the id, you won't want it passed as a GET parameter.

Comment: I like the idea of this method and I have it working to a certain extent, but I don't know how to get to the other page as it just says Object not found

Comment: You're best using sessions for this, it will make life a lot simpler for you, down the road. @user3191346

Comment: The href of your link is incorrect.  Try opening the link in a new tab and inspect the URL that opens.  Now look at the script you have created and double check its location.  The two locations are most likely not in the same location.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried sessions but it will only output the last row in the form and not the one I clicked

Comment: @Fred-ii-:  Why don't you write that up in an answer?  My php is a little rusty and I can't think how you'd use a session to know an id that the user hasn't chosen yet.

Comment: @SurrealDreams I understand my URL is wrong because the code you gave me has the even id in it, and my document does not

Comment: If your query is "SELECT * FROM event" and your event table has an id field, then your id is available in your document, just like the other fields are.

Comment: I've given the OP a few links (underneath the original question) to visit and base him/herself on those. That, in my view is probably the best way to achieve this. If an ID hasn't been chosen yet, then that's where conditional statements come in handy. @SurrealDreams

Comment: Still can't suss this out. Sessions are not setting for the individual record, but only for the last in the form. The HREF method is also not working for me

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd post the code you're attempting to use for the link.  The schema of the event table might also be useful.